# Why I get this error? SQL0551N The statement failed because the authorization ID

Tags: db2, db2-luw, toad-data-point

I want to create a view from another view that I have select statement privilege. However, I can't and I am getting this error. Do you know why? Do I need other type of Select privilege?

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = SCHEMA1;

CREATE VIEW NEWSCHEMA.MYVIEW AS SELECT  * FROM DB1.SCHEMA1.VIEW1

WITH NO ROW MOVEMENT;

SET CURRENT SCHEMA = NEWSCHEMA;

COMMIT;
```

full error msg:

> Category  Line    Position    Timestamp   Duration    Message Error   3   0   01/27/2023
> 11:24:05 AM   0:00:00.007  - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42501]
> [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0551N  The statement failed because the
> authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege
> to perform the operation.  Authorization ID: "NEWSCHEMA".  Operation:
> "SELECT". Object: "SCHEMA1.VIEW1".

```
SELECT GRANTEE, GRANTEETYPE, CONTROLAUTH, SELECTAUTH FROM SYSCAT.TABAUTH WHERE (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME) = ('SCHEMA1', 'VIEW1') AND GRANTEETYPE IN ('U', 'R')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with a full error message.

Comment: Do you really try to create a view on a federated object using 3-part name `DB1.SCHEMA1.VIEW1`? Or is this a typo, and you try to create a view on a local view (or on a nickname referencing a federated object)?

Comment: DB1 is the database name and then View1 is in the Schema1. I am trying to create a view in my personal schema inside the same DB1. So it will be DB1.NEWSCHEMA.MYVIEW

Comment: Edit your question with the result of the following query. `SELECT GRANTEE, GRANTEETYPE, CONTROLAUTH, SELECTAUTH
FROM SYSCAT.TABAUTH
WHERE (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME) = ('SCHEMA1', 'VIEW1')
AND GRANTEETYPE IN ('U', 'R')`.

Comment: `O5Z` - is this your user name you run the CREATE VIEW statement as?

Comment: No it is not. the thing is I can create a select statement but not create view? I realized they given access to group role. I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is highly like because of the following [CREATE VIEW](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-view) authorization requirement:

> **Authorization**
> The privileges held by the authorization ID of the
> statement must include at least one of the following authorities:
>
> IMPLICIT_SCHEMA authority on the database, if the implicit or explicit schema name of the view does not exist
> CREATEIN privilege on the schema, if the schema name of the view refers to an existing schema
> SCHEMAADM authority on the schema, if the schema name of the view refers to an existing schema
> DBADM authority
>
> and at least one of the following authorities for each table, view, or
> nickname identified in any fullselect:
>
> **CONTROL** privilege on that table, view, or nickname
> **SELECT** privilege on that table, view, or nickname
> SELECTIN privilege on the schema containing the table, view, or nickname
> DATAACCESS authority on the schema containing the table, view, or nickname
> DATAACCESS authority
> ...
> **Group privileges are not considered for any table or view specified in the CREATE VIEW statement.**

So, you may really have an ability to SELECT from this view, but you probably have it via some group membership, but not personally or via some role.
This is the reason you get this error.
You may ask your SECADM or view owner grant your authorization id a `SELECT` privilege to resolve the problem.

Comment: I am not sure if you see my comment, but our IT team is pushing back to give me access because they say too much authority is required to create views on production schemas, but why? these are my team schema and personal schema. Any input from you would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your request. If you or your team want to change the rules, you may open some enhancement request (so called Idea) with IBM support on this.

Comment: @Mark_Barinstein sorry, the question is that IT Department pushing back to give me access because they say too much authority on the database! I was wondering getting this type of access to create view on my own schema will have any security issues on the main production schema??

Comment: I have no idea why the owner of the base view doesn't want to grant SELECT on it to you personally. It's a question.to this person. If you want just to reference an existing object, you may use [CREATE ALIAS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-alias) instead with  your schema name.